# Custom fields uploaded not available for pdf merge

Tags: custom-fields, pdf, dompdf

Environment is Wordpress 6.0 and CiviCRM 5.49.0

The org I work for gives out scholarships on a yearly basis, so the applicant has to provide a couple of pieces of documentation, like transcripts and a photo.  In the image below, this would be field ID 44.

[image: custom field file upload]

Front-end works great:

[image: front end]

Dashboard works great:

[image: contact dashboard]

The staff would like to use the pdf merge feature so that the scholarship committee can get all of the information in one page.  This doesn't work, though.  Adding the custom token to the document merge just leaves a blank space:

[image: custom token in merge dialogue window]

I can get every other field needed from the contact record, including custom fields that are not file uploads.

I have checked:

- user permissions (I'm admin, so I ought to have access)
- folder permissions (included chmod-ding the folder to 777)
- the files are present in the correct folder, but the file access token has been added, so now it's named transcript_398bf50762b843fbcf65062937095717.txt
- I even did strange stuff like stop forcing ssl:

[image: seriously, turned off ssl verification]

If I export the contact's information in a csv, I do get the correct url for the filename:
https://hidden.org/civicrm/file/?reset=1&id=44&eid=2&fcs=f89b80fc27e9f265b511beb089cfffdf6363e953e5e61ac9d66a7000d710f12f_1653991338_168

So, how do I actually make this token available for pdf's?  Barring that, can I somehow reconstruct the URL so that the staff can see the photos and download the custom fields they need?  Any advice or ideas on this would be greatly appreciated.  I'm afraid I've missed a simple setting somewhere and I've been working through this for a week now!

Thank you!!

Comment: so you want the path to the file to be inserted in your pdf?

Comment: Yes, I would like the staff to be able to click on it and have the document fetched from the site and embed photos, if needed.  I just can't get a handle on the file access token.

Comment: i suspect such a token has not been made by anyone but you could ask also on https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/

Comment: Also note that that url it generates is time-limited for security reasons, so it lessens the value of including it in a pdf. I know that export does output it, but I also don't see much value in that.

Comment: I found this issue:  https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2410  so I can see it isn't just me.

Comment: good find. but not clear if Michael progressed his extension idea